# Mail::Address not parsing correctly emails with comma

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use `Mail::Address` to parse an email address, however the output is not as expected:

```
Mail::Address.new('Arnold, Roa <aroa@so.com>').address
=> "Arnold"
```

What is the problem and what alternatives do I have?

Comment: The comma is what's throwing it off. Does the string with the comma conform to the published standard?

Comment: Hope this is a fake address or Arnold may got a lot of spam ;) J/K see my answer

Comment: The comma, without the whole thing being quoted, appears to violate the RFC (RFC5322 is the current, I believe)

Comment: Mandrill is sending me mails with comma on the name, I guess is how the sender is reporting his name.

Answer (score 1):

This works, not sure why the comma is there:

```
Mail::Address.new('Arnold, Roa <aroa@so.com>'.gsub(',','')).address
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created an issue on the github project: https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/1219

In the meanwhile I created this monkey patch (which is not a good practice and should be avoided):

```
class Mail::Address
  class << self
    def new(value = nil)
      if value.is_a? String
        value = value.gsub(',', ' ')
      end

      super(value)
    end
  end
end
```